# How to find the coordinates (longitude, latitude) of a point in an aerial image?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, latitude-longitude, maps, geolocation

I will be receiving drone images from an associate. It'll have longitudes/latitudes values from the corners of the image.  I don't have access to his image processing S/W.  It'll be in a relatively small area 1,000,000m².  Not sure if I would need the accuracy of something like the Haversine formula.

I need to find the coordinates (longitude, latitude) of a given point (trucks for example) in the image.  This point is ever changing image to image.
I'm seeking an equation/Java code/Python code etc.

Comment: How is the "given point" being given? As a pixel coordinate, or are you having to view the image and find the truck? If you can persuade them to supply a GeoTIFF image then any GIS will tell you the lat-long of any point. Otherwise given the corner coordinates you can create a "world file" and then the image can be loaded into a GIS with spatial referencing.

Comment: If the image is georectified and has coordinates embedded in a GeoTIFF or world file, this is a basic task (once you choose a software environment and processing tool), but without this there's not enough information here to answer. We do expect coding questions to include an attempt at coding.